# LINQ Query Error - where clause in foreach loop

Tags: c#, linq

I wrote a LINQ query but I have some problem in executing `where` clause in `foreach` loop.

```
using (DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext(("ConnectionString")))
{
    Table<NOTIF_SCHED> NOTIF_SCHED_alias = db.GetTable<NOTIF_SCHED>();
    IQueryable<NOTIF_SCHED> notif_sched_data = from sched in NOTIF_SCHED_alias select sched;

    foreach (var notif_sched_data_value in notif_sched_data)
    {
        string a = notif_sched_data_value.NOTIF_RPT_ID.ToString();

        Table<mainframe_replication> mainframe_replications_alias = db.GetTable<mainframe_replication>();
        IQueryable<mainframe_replication> mainframe_replications_data =
            from mfrepl in mainframe_replications_alias
            where (mfrepl.RPT_ID.Equals(a))
            select mfrepl;

        foreach (var mainframe_replication_data_value in mainframe_replications_data)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("hi");
        }
    }
}
```

I am not able to use `Where` clause in line:

```
IQueryable<mainframe_replication> mainframe_replications_data =
    from mfrepl in mainframe_replications_alias
    where (mfrepl.RPT_ID.Equals(a))
    select mfrepl;**
```

Can someone please help and check if the syntax is wrong.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Please put more effort into formatting your code in questions. It was *really* hard to read before I edited it.

Comment: When I check the generated SQl,it comes out to be:  SELECT [t0].[REPL_GUID], [t0].[REPL_TYPE], [t0].[RPT_ID]
FROM [mainframe_replication] AS [t0]
WHERE [t0].[RPT_ID] = @p0. I think the problem is with :@P0".No error message ,it just doesnt go in the loop

Comment: Rather than pulling down an entire table, and getting a corresponding record for each item in the results, do a join to get exactly the data you need in just one query.  It'll save you a *lot* of round trips.

Comment: `WHERE [t0].[RPT_ID] = @p0` this is your where clause, your code seems to work. It filters and selects something.

Comment: @Servy-Thanks for the advise.I will try to do that once I get some more time after submitting this code.But still any reson why "Where" clause is not working.Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri-but i am passing the value i.e string a directly.It should take value of "a". am i right Sir?

Comment: yes but that value is passed by parameter `@p0`. You can see in your query something like `sp_executesql 'SELECT [t0].[REPL_GUID], [t0].[REPL_TYPE], [t0].[RPT_ID] FROM [mainframe_replication] AS [t0] WHERE [t0].[RPT_ID] = @p0', @p0 = 'a'`.

Comment: Maybe it doesn't go in the loop because the where clause results in no data being returned.

Comment: I checked again and found that in loop`Table<NOTIF_SCHED> NOTIF_SCHED_alias = db.GetTable<NOTIF_SCHED>();
                        IQueryable<NOTIF_SCHED> notif_sched_data = from sched in NOTIF_SCHED_alias                           select sched;

                        foreach (var notif_sched_data_value in notif_sched_data)`, the generated sql when run in sql gives three different rows but while debugging .Net code,3 rows with same value keeps on repeating i.e i.e  **notif_sched_data** gives 3 different rows but same when used in **foreach** loop gives repeat rows with same value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the same thing and run much faster:

```
using (DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext(("ConnectionString")))
{
    var ids = db.NOTIF_SCHEDs.Select(x=>x.NOTIF_RPT_ID).ToArray();
    var repl = db.mainframe_replication
        .Where(mfrepl=>ids.Contains(mfrepl.RPT_ID));

        foreach (var mainframe_replication_data_value in repl)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("hi");
        }
    }
}
```

If NOTIF_RPT_ID is not a string, and RPT_ID is, you can do this:

```
using (DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext(("ConnectionString")))
{
    var ids = db.NOTIF_SCHEDs.Select(x=>x.NOTIF_RPT_ID.ToString()).ToArray();
    var repl = db.mainframe_replication
        .Where(mfrepl=>ids.Contains(mfrepl.RPT_ID));

        foreach (var mainframe_replication_data_value in repl)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("hi");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sir,this code says that **var doesn`t exist in current context** and *type expected* (after = sign).Do i need to add property sub for var?

Comment: Sorry, perhaps `as` is a reserved word, updated answer using `ids` instead.  Probably better than `a` anyhow.

Comment: Appologies for disturbing again but now **var ids = db.NOTIF_SCHEDs.Select(x=>x.NOTIF_RPT_ID).ToArray();** doesn`t give any data.Did I missed something? Also,db. gives option as *NOTIF_SCHEDs* and not *NOTIF_SCHED* .Does it affect anyhow?

Comment: The only way I can think of that it would give no data is if your `NOTIF_SCHED` table had no records in it.  Double check that your table has data, and that your connection string is pointing to the correct database (Is it pointing to a test database?)  Sorry, `NOTIF_SCHEDs` is the correct one to use.

Comment: I checked and Notif_Sched contains 3 rows Sir.But Still Thanks a lot .

Comment: The same may be true of `mainframe_replication` vs `mainframe_replications`.  EF will automatically pluralize the tables, those are the ones you should use.

Comment: Table names in SQL server are case sensitive.  `Notif_Sched` and `NOTIF_SCHED` aren't the same table.  Is this a MSSQL database?

Comment: Thanks again.i will try to figure out why it is giving 0 rows.

Comment: Yes Sir,It is MS Sql Server 2008 database.But where to change the database name as it comes via Intelisense feature after  "."

Comment: The database is specified here `new DataClasses1DataContext(("ConnectionString")))` the intellisense after the `.` is the table name.

Comment: oh Yes,I checked,everything is correct ,even the database name.I will look into this Sir.Thanks for giving a way atleast .Great Thanks

Comment: Thanks Sir,I forgot to add  `Table<NOTIF_SCHED> NOTIF_SCHED_alias = db.GetTable<NOTIF_SCHED>();` line in my code.Afte adding this,it is working.Thanks a lot